# I get reactjs serviceWorker.js instead of registerServiceWorker.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I build with "create-react-app projectname" 
At the first time I had registerServiceWorker.js in src directory 
but suddenly when I build new project I get just serviceWorker.js

1. Why suddenly I get serviceWorker.js file when I buile new project?
   ( Of course it works fine when I copy registerServiceWorker file. bt I just wonder )
2. And How can I fix to get registerServiceWorker.js when I create new app?

   - I am using node(v8.12.0), yarn(1.10.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like with the release of Create React App 2.0 they replaced registerServiceWorker.js with serviceWorker.js, and now service workers with CRA are optional.